# Map Style in ChartLabel in Mathematica

Tags: coding-style, dictionary, wolfram-mathematica

```
ChartLabels -> Placed[{{Style["0", Bold, 18, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]},
                       {Style["1", Bold, 18, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]},
                       {Style["2", Bold, 18, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]},
                       {Style["3", Bold, 18, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]},
                       {Style["4", Bold, 18, 
                       FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}}, 
                       {{.1, .15}, {.3, .15}, {.5, .15}, {.7, .15},{.9, .15}}]
```

First, I am sorry this is even an embarass to myself, but I could not figure out how to use a function in there.

How can I make this tighter ?

I tried nesting a Switch unsuccessfully yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean something like

```
ChartLabels -> Placed@@Transpose[Table[{
   {Style[n[[1]], Bold, 18, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}, {n[[2]], .15}}, 
   {n, Transpose[{ToString/@Range[0, 4], Range[.1, .9, .2]}]}]]
```

Another option is maybe to set the [BaseStyle](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BaseStyle.html) for the chart. 
Or maybe [LabelingFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LabelingFunction.html).

Answer (score 6):

I'm interested to know what kind of chart you're creating with this.

Anyway, `Placed` takes a third argument that can be applied to the labels, so you could use something like:

```
ChartLabels -> 
 Placed[
   {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4"}, 
   {{.1, .15}, {.3, .15}, {.5, .15}, {.7, .15}, {.9, .15}}, 
   Style[#, Bold, 18, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"] &
   ]
```

Comment: Well, I am just trying to label some "Count charts". Where subject never chose something, chose it 1 time out of 4, 2 out of 4 etc... Just posted another question related trying to use list plot. I must say I am tempted to use Graphics and draw thing myself at this point :-)